# My collector does not seem to work in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

````
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('event-host')
        .setDescription('Hosts/Creates a new Event.'),

    async execute(interaction) 
    {

        if (interaction.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR)) 
        {
        
            return interaction.reply('```Enter the Name of your Event:```')
            .then(() => 
            {
                const filter = m => m.content.startsWith('t');
                const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter , time: 5000, max: 3 });
                collector.on('collect', m => interaction.channel.send(`Collected ${m.content}`));
                collector.on('end', collected => interaction.channel.send(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
            });

        }
        else
        {
            return interaction.reply({ content: '```You must have Administrator permissions to be able to use this command!```', ephemeral: true});
        }
    },
};
````

The collector ends but does not collect. I tried it with `awaitMessages` too and that also ended with 'catch' but it did not collect either. Maybe it has something to do with `async` but I am not sure. I tried filter to set to `m.author.id == interaction.user.id` but that doesn't even make the collector work.

Comment: Did you respond to the collector within 5 seconds (because `time: 5000`) and that message started with the letter 't'?

Comment: @GodderE2D Yes ofcourse, I did reply within the time. It didn't collect it, it just gave the reply that it took  no collections after time ends.

Comment: Bump? I need help.